# What is the most efficient way of comparing 1 set of data with another involving data ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, associative-array, bulk-collect

I am trying to come up with the most efficient way of comparing current production data with data where I have collapsed date ranges.

So basically I have some production data where a user will be connected to a given plan and then possible switch to another or not be on a plan for a month etc....

For example:

```
Plan A  1/1/15 - 6/30/15
Plan A  7/1/15 - 9/30/15
Plan B  10/1/15 - 10/30/15
Plan A  1/1/16  - 3/31/16
```

Then these dates are collapsed, in the case above the return would be 3 spans

```
Plan A  1/1/15 - 9/30/15
Plan B  10/1/15 - 10/30/15
Plan A  1/1/16  - 3/31/16
```

The production collapsed spans are put into an associative array so that I can go through and check them against the image that is made from the prior process of this run.

I also load the dataset of the current collapsed spans into an array so that it can be accessed quicker instead of going to the table for each row of the production data array.  This is done by creating a datatype object that is the same as the table I am populating, then bulk collect like

```
 SELECT plan_obj(pk, plan, effective_begin, effective_end)
   BULK COLLECT INTO customer_plan_tbl 
   FROM customer_plan
  WHERE id = P_ID;
```

So at this point I have 2 associative arrays filled and ordered by the member and their effectivity.

So what would be the best way to compare for differences and other changes?

So far I loop through the production data, load another 3rd array temporarily with just that members data from the current collapsed data like:

```
SELECT customer_id, plan, effective_begin, effective_end
  BULK COLLECT
  INTO customer_plan_compare
  FROM TABLE(customer_plan_tbl )
 WHERE customer_id = customer_plan_tbl(indx).customer_id AND
          plan     = customer_plan_tbl(indx).plan; 
             ORDER BY effective_begin, effective_end, plan;
```

Now if this collection has 0 rows, I know I can add the new record, moving on, loop through this collection and compare it to the current row of outer loop, if it is the same, nothing to do it is when there are differences, things need to be updated.

This seems like a lot of overhead to do for each row, I was just wondering if there was a better way to compare to collections for differences based on a customer and their spans of effective datas.

The other problem is I am limiting the size of the bulk collects so if the same customer spans different bulk collects, I will have to resolve that.

So the goal is to keep this new table in sync with production data just with collapsed windows of data spans.

Comment: Your approach seems way too complicated.  Why not just use a query on the original table?

Comment: it looks like you are reinventing Oracle's [materialized views](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28326/repmview.htm)

Comment: The thought process was that instead of querying the table (on disc) over and over, I would load it into memory (associative array) then comparing because the dates could change in many different ways.  But yes I may be over complicating things.

Comment: Oracle's MINUS operator could be useful here. `SELECT t1key FROM t1 MINUS SELECT t2key FROM t2` will show you which rows are in t1 but not t2 (based on a primary key you can match on across both tables). Then `SELECT t2key FROM t2 MINUS SELECT t1key FROM t1` gives you rows to insert in other direction. Now do the same thing again with all columns of the table in the select lists to determine where an update is required to get tables in sync.

Comment: I ended up using the MULTISET operator to do a EXCEPT which is essentially a MINUS between 2 collections.  Only problem is that it can't handle complex (more than 1 column) collections (associative arrays) so you have to create a OBJECT with a function so that it can sort.  Well I did this but it simply runs forever so I am still trying to figure this out at this point